# Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Cannot parse Firebase url. Please use https://<YOUR FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com but database url is not firebaseio.com expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo, react-native-ios

I'm using Expo SDK for my ios app, when I try to write data in the firebase database but I'm getting the error. ****Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Cannot parse Firebase URL. Please use https://.firebaseio.com*****

My firebase config file is

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
  projectId: "xxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
  measurementId: "xxxxxx"
};
```

my function that stores the data is

```
signUp = () => {
   const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
   let userid = user.uid;

   firebase
     .database()
     .ref(`users/${userid}`)
     .set({
       firstname: this.state.firstname,
       lastname: this.state.lastname,
       password: this.state.password,
       email: this.state.email,
       dob: this.state.dob,
       postcode: this.state.postcode,
     })
     .then(() => {
       alert("user created");
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       alert("error");
     });
 };
```

My database rules are set to true for reading and write.

I have tried the following database URL but none of them work.

```
const firebaseConfig = {

  databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.europe-west1.firebaseio.com",
 
};
const firebaseConfig = {

  databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
 
};
```

Looking for help, please

Comment: It'd really help to see exactly where the error message is coming from. But I'd recommend explicitly passing the URL into the database initialization with: `firebase.database().ref("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebasedatabase.app")` as a workaround either way.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried that, it gives me the same error

Answer (score 6):

*firebaser here*

Somehow Expo seems to pin you on Firebase SDK [version 7.9](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_790_-_february_20_2020), which was released in February 2020. This predates the addition of the `firebasedatabase.app` URLs, which happened in May 2020, and was released in version [7.15.4](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#realtime-database_9) of the JavaScript SDK, as far as I can see.

The problem disappears when I upgrade the SDK dependency to 7.14.5, despite the Expo Snack editor showing an error when I do:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native-paper": "3.6.0",
    "expo-constants": "~9.3.1",
    "firebase": "7.14.5"
  }
}
```

My recommendation would be to upgrade to the latest versions of the SDK, as shown in the configuration snippets in the Firebase console and documentation.

Comment: I upgrades my dependency and it still gives the same error. My dependencies are

`{
"@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "^9.3.5",
    "expo-firebase-recaptcha": "^1.3.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-linking": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.8.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "~8.6.0",
    "firebase": "^7.14.5",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz"
}`

Comment: That's interesting, as it works for me here: https://snack.expo.io/ij7acLi0V

Comment: yes, it is very strange. I am using the latest SDK dependency and I'm not sure what is wrong. I will keep debugging it

Comment: Hey @gangataarun. Did you make any progress here? Given that I was able to reproduce the message with the Firebase SDK version, and able to fix it by upgrading to a newer version, I'm quite convinced it must be version related. If you haven't fixed it yet, can you reproduce it as a Expo snack, so I can have a look?

Answer (score 5):

Upgrading **Firebase package** to the latest version fixes the issue

```
"firebase": "^8.2.3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you initialize the config? Something like this.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/storage';
import 'firebase/functions';

interface ConfigProps {
    apiKey: string;
    authDomain: string;
    databaseURL: string;
    projectId: string;
    storageBucket: string;
    messagingSenderId: string;
    appId: string;
}

const config: ConfigProps = {
    apiKey: '******************',
    authDomain: '******************',
    databaseURL: '******************',
    projectId: '******************,
    storageBucket: '******************',
    messagingSenderId: '******************',
    appId: '******************',
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.firestore();

export default firebase;
```

Comment: yes I have initialize the config which i call in my app.js

`import * as firebase from "firebase";
import firebaseAppconfig from "./variables/firebase";

// PROVIDE VALID FIREBASE CONFIG HERE
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
const FIREBASE_CONFIG: any = firebaseAppconfig;

try {
  if (FIREBASE_CONFIG.apiKey) {
    firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG);
  }
} catch (err) {
  // ignore app already initialized error on snack
} `