# Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Cannot parse Firebase url. Please use https://<YOUR FIREBASE>

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web

I have looked at [Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Cannot parse Firebase url. Please use https://<YOUR FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com but database url is not firebaseio.com expo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65725442/error-firebase-fatal-error-cannot-parse-firebase-url-please-use-https-your) and I don't believe it applies.

So...Im using flutter on the web FYI and testing in chrome.

In my main.dart I use:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  setupDependencies();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

And doing this did eliminate some errors, but not all errors.

Also, in another file I have a global var:

```
final DatabaseReference kDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
```

And when trying to use kDatabase to operate on firebase, I get

```
Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Cannot parse Firebase url. Please use https://<YOUR
FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com
```

I have done  `dart pub get firebase` ..and it says it is up to date.

My firebase_options.dart was generated automatically from the firebase website.

relevant pub spec:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  dartz: ^0.10.0
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  
  freezed_annotation: ^1.1.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
  provider: ^6.0.1
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.3
  firebase_database: ^9.0.3
  firebase_analytics: ^9.0.3
  firebase_storage: ^10.0.5 
  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.3
  firebase_remote_config: ^2.0.2
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^4.0.2
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.4
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like you should declare database config if you want to use it no? Or if it gets generated, what does it look like?

Comment: @html_programmer  I'm a complete n00b to flutter, can you point me in right direction to this config? Thank you 

Comment: Well no, I don't use Flutter LOL! But in order to connect to a db, you need a connection, just makes sense. This is probably what the url is referring to. This should be mentioned in the docs somewhere of whatever package you're using, and probably you should find the db connection string somewhere on your Firebase account I assume. Or perhaps you can generate some config file, I dunno. It's always sort of the same thing this kind of actions.

Answer (score 2):

If you have used `$ flutterfire configure` to configure firebase to your flutter project as shown in [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/#generating-firebase-options) before adding Realtime Database, you will have to run the command again to reconfigure your project or add "databaseURL" to the FirebaseOptions in your `lib/firebase_options.dart`.

Your `lib/firebase_options.dart` should look something like this:

```
// inside lib/firebase_options.dart

// ...

static const FirebaseOptions web = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: '...',
    appId: '...',
    messagingSenderId: '...',
    projectId: 'project-id',
    authDomain: 'project-id.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://your-database-id.firebasedatabase.app', // IMPORTANT!
    storageBucket: 'project-id.appspot.com',
    measurementId: '...',
);

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I my case I forgot to add Database URL which you will get in
Firebase Console -> Project Settings-> Your Apps-> Select your app.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: got to your firebaseOptions

```
copy ( apiKey: 'AIzaSyBm70TH68natnHg_Ueq3-eKpEKHdaj0p2k',
    appId: '1:733077779058:web:9fb7ba429c9fbf03b608eb',
    messagingSenderId: '733077779058',
    projectId: 'socialmedia-9cd65',
    authDomain: 'socialmedia-9cd65.firebaseapp.com',
    storageBucket: 'socialmedia-9cd65.appspot.com',
    measurementId: 'G-LTHTMKWY94',)
```

These parameters, according to your project link mac, web, android,
add to these pramaters to your main file options:

```
FirebaseOptions(apiKey: 'AIzaSyBm70TH68natnHg_Ueq3-eKpEKHdaj0p2k',
    appId: '1:733077779058:web:9fb7ba429c9fbf03b608eb',
    messagingSenderId: '733077779058',
    projectId: 'socialmedia-9cd65',
    authDomain: 'socialmedia-9cd65.firebaseapp.com',
    storageBucket: 'socialmedia-9cd65.appspot.com',
    measurementId: 'G-LTHTMKWY94',)
```

Now you only required a dataBaseUrl
go to your realdata base copy the url that  https://socialmedia-9cd65-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com

and then add the  another parameter "databaseURL" in the above section and copy paste the url infront of "databaseURL=https://socialmedia-9cd65-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com

Now your error should b sovled

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I checked all of the firebase configuration stuff, and it was still happening. I tried FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("url here") instead of just FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref() because I thought that would bypass whatever config stuff was wrong. It still didn't work. I thought it must be a dependency conflict so I move everything out of my project so it was just a main pulling from Realtime database. It worked, so I started slowly adding my code back to find the conflict. I never found it and its working now. This isn't a real solution, but I thought I'd share incase anyone is in my situation.